# Why the two outputs aren't equal in Pytorch derivation?

Tags: python, pytorch, derivative

I thought from the view in the derivation of composite functions(Chain rule), these two representations should be equal.

```
import torch

x = torch.rand(3, requires_grad=True)
y = x + 2
z = 2 * y * y
z = z.mean()
z.backward()
print(4 * (x + 2))
print(x.grad)
```

But the outputs are as follows:

```
tensor([ 8.5011,  8.6625, 11.9508], grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
tensor([2.8337, 2.8875, 3.9836])
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, just off by a constant factor of 3. That is because when you take mean of `z`, that essentially sums each element of `z` and divides by 3 (because here your tensor is a 3 element vector). So essentially a 1/3 factor appears in the gradient, which is multiplied upstream.